# Blood Pressure / Pulse Correlation

Tags: blood-pressure

I've been working on trying to lower my blood pressure.
As part of that, I've been reading up on what blood pressure is, and how it is impacted by exercise.

From what I understand, people who are fitter tend to have lower resting heart rates because their heart muscle is stronger, which means that it can move more blood per beat than a less healthy person, so as a result, it requires less beats per minute (as an example).

My question though, as it relates to blood pressure is, if the heart is stronger, and therefore moving more blood per beat, wouldn't that increase the amount of blood being pumped per beat mean an increase on the force against your arteries (i.e higher blood pressure), since more blood is being moved at a time?

Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: Are you aware that blood pressure is two numbers? Do you know what each number roughly represents? Do you know which of the two numbers is considered more important for declaring someone to have high blood pressure? Show your research in your question.

Comment: yes, I’m familiar with systolic and diastolic values. one represents the force when the heart contracts the other when the heart relaxes. with respect to which is more important, my understanding is that both are important. having isolated high bp with either number isn’t good to my understanding

Comment: Remember that blood pressure is a function of cardiac output and total peripheral vascular resistance not just cardiac output